# How to calculate the current produced by a solar panel?

Tags: solar-cell, photodiode, math, physics, solar-energy

The equation for calculating current when given voltage and temperature is known as the 5-Parameter model ie.

\$I = I_{ph} - I_o[\exp(\frac{V + R_sI}{nV_t})-1] - (\frac{V+R_sI}{R_{sh}})\$

Since this is a non-linear implicit equation, we use the Lambert W function to solve for \$I\$, so the equation becomes

\$I=\frac{(I_{ph}+I_o)-V/R_{sh}}{1+R_s/R_{sh}}-\frac{nV_t}{R_s}W(\frac{I_oR_s}{nV_t(1+R_s/R_{sh})}\exp(\frac{V}{nV_t}(1-\frac{R_s}{R_s+R_{sh}})+\frac{(I_{ph}+I_o)R_s}{nV_t(1+R_s/R_{sh})}))\$

where \$W(x)\$ is the Lambert W function.

Now, assuming that these 5 parameters are known,

(\$I_{ph}=6.6, I_o=1.297*10^{-7}, R_s=0.33, R_{sh}=198.88, n=1.038\$)

and the input voltage and temperature are,

\$V=200, T=45^0C\$

Now if I substitute the values into the equation, the current turns out to be negative infinity, and only when the voltage is around 1V, the current is normal. Am I missing something? The value inside the \$\exp(x)\$ turns out to be more than 1000, and this is the reason it becomes infinity. I am not able to produce a normal I-V curve for the solar panel because of this.

Here is the code that calculates the value

```
from scipy import constants
from scipy.special import lambertw
import numpy as np

# Iph, Io, Rs, Rsh, n
params = [6.6, 1.2E-7, 0.33, 198.88, 1.038]

def func(V, T, Iph, Io, Rs, Rsh, n):
    RsRsh = 1 + Rs/Rsh
    print(RsRsh)
    Ipho = Iph + Io
    firstTerm = (Ipho - (V/Rsh)) / RsRsh
    thermalVoltage = (273.15 + T)*(constants.k) / constants.e
    secondTerm = (n*thermalVoltage) / Rs
    thirdTerm = (Io*Rs)/(n*thermalVoltage*RsRsh)
    fourthTerm = (V/(n*thermalVoltage))*(1-(Rs/(Rs+Rsh)))
    fifthTerm = ((Iph+Io)*Rs)/(n*thermalVoltage*RsRsh)
    exp = np.exp(fourthTerm+fifthTerm)
    secondPart = thirdTerm * exp
    value = firstTerm - secondTerm*lambertw(secondPart)
    return value


def main():
    V = 200
    T = 45
    print(func(V, T, *params))
```

Comment: https://pvpmc.sandia.gov/modeling-steps/2-dc-module-iv/diode-equivalent-circuit-models/de-soto-5-parameter-model/

Comment: Did U leave out the constant for Ns, the number of cells \$\dfrac{(V+N_sR_s *I)}{N_snV_t}\$  in 1st Eqn.

Comment: I'm not too sure whether or not it isn't expected. A solar cell acts like a bit like a diode, so biasing it in the forward regime using 200V will likely cause an overflow (and break the solar cell?).

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75. Wow I literally read tens of paper and none of them had an equation with cells in series. But yeah, I'll have to add the number of cells that are in series. Now I have to figure out how to convert that function into a Lambert W form.

Comment: @SvenB. I think what SunnyskyguyEE75 said is correct. The panel I'm looking at has 26 cells in series and that's why the voltage is that high.